# Where is jme/j2me used nowadays?

Tags: java-me, jvm, embedded

I just read some [news](http://www.h-online.com/developer/news/item/Qualcomm-launches-development-platform-for-the-Internet-of-Things-1779313.html) about Qualcomm launching an internet of things development platform on top of JME and I was wondering where is jme/j2me used nowadays. I know it was used for some old mobile phones and apparently you can still use for developing application for Bada and Symbian.

But besides that is there any other field where is it used? Can someone exemplify other areas where Jme is used or point to an updated list of embedded devices implementing a jvm compliant with jme?

The newest related inquire I saw around the topic was this [forum discussion](http://www.coderanch.com/t/529810/JME/Mobile/Alive) which did not bring that much light to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think it has spread, with feature phones, into places where smartphones are still pretty expensive.  As an anecdote, my scripting language for phones, Hecl, does not get a lot of traction these days, by and large, but *does* seem to get a lot of attention in places like Indonesia.